# Utility Patent enforcing

Tags: us7503696

Who has the right to enforce patent us7503696

I imported a product from China that is sold on ebay and amazon and many trade shows. Now a company in the US is threatening to close me down due to infringing on a similar product they sell that has a us utility patent owned by someone in S Korea.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you saw at google patents that it was assigned last year:

> ```
> LEGAL EVENTS        Date      Code    Event    Description
>                   Jun 28, 2013    AS            Assignment
> ```
>
> Owner name: DAE SUNG HI-TECH CO., LTD, KOREA, REPUBLIC OF
>   Free format text: ASSIGNMENT OF ASSIGNORS INTEREST;ASSIGNOR:SEHYANG INDUSTRIAL CO., LTD;REEL/FRAME:030710/0859
>   Effective date: 20130509

A U.S. patent gives the owner the right to stop others from making, selling, using in the U.S. or importing into the U.S.

Comment: I don't think they are asking who the Assignee is. He wants to know why a US company is enforcing the patent when the Assignee is a Korean company.

Comment: Thanks - the U.S. company may have an exclusive license from the Korean company or be a subsidiary of the Korean company. Also, there is no requirement to record assignments at the USPTO. The patent may have been assigned by the Korean company to the American company but not recorded with the USPTO.

Comment: @George White The Chinese manufacturer claims to have 2 serperate chinese patents for this item. Does that have any pull here in the US?

Comment: Patents are territorial. A Chinese patent could be used to stop people from making, selling using and importing into *China*.

Answer (score 0):

a key point here is that you've now been made aware that you're in violation of a US patent.  Assuming you agree that the patent covers the item in question, even though it may seem unfair (given the availability of the item), you should stop using it.

Perhaps the patent owner will give you a use license if you send them a payment?  If you can't come to an agreement with the patent owner (or their assignee), you've got to stop using/selling the item in the US, or you're open to damages, if they were to proceed and try to sue you.